# Creating a generic field of type X and setting its value as (unrelated) type Y through reflection does not cause an IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I've been playing around with setting fields dynamically using reflection.
When it came to generic classes, there is one snag.
Consider this code:

**Wrapper.java**:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    private T var;

    public void setVar(T var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public T getVar() {
        return this.var;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Wrapper<Integer> integer = new Wrapper<Integer>();
            Field f = integer.getClass().getDeclaredField("var");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(integer, "test");

            System.out.println("Assignable: " + f.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class));
            System.out.println("Var value: " + integer.getVar());
            System.out.println("Int value: " + integer.getVar().intValue());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The main method prints out

```
Assignable: true
Var value: test
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

From the documentation [set(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> If the specified object argument is null, the method throws a
>   NullPointerException. If the specified object argument is not an
>   instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field, the
>   method throws an IllegalArgumentException.

Shouldn't the following piece of code throw IllegalArgumentException?
How is it possible to check whether the field can be set even if using generic variable types?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, any generic type information is erased at the moment of `f.set(integer, "test")` due to [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: I understand that the type of the field is Object due to type erasure, but how can I check whether I can set the field and will not cause cast exception later?